# Font size in html using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

in my project I need to right some big text, so in my css file I wrote:

```
#wrong_answer
{
    color: red;
    font-size: 30;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and in my js file:

```
function wrong_answer()
{    
    $("body").append("<p id='wrong_answer'>Is not correct</p>");
};
```

and finaly I got red text, but very-very small and if I change font-size the size of text doesnt changes.

so question is why cant I change font-size?

Comment: have you tried to add a unit? e.g. `font-size: 30px` ?

Comment: `in my project I need to right some big text` You can use something like `text-align: right;` to `right` your text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`30` what? `30px`, `30pt`, `30%`, `30em`? You have an invalid property value there.

When using jQuery you can specify just an integer but that's because jQuery treats integers like pixel values, e.g.:

```
//this will work
$([selection]).css({ fontSize : 30 });
```

Here are some great docs for `font-size:` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

**UPDATE**

You can use your developer tools (Chrome/Firefox/Safari for sure) to inspect the CSS associated with an element. When an invalid property value is encountered, these developer tools will alert you to the fact.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the "unit of size" . . .

```
font-size: 30px;
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSS declaration `font-size: 30` is invalid and ignored by conforming browsers. If you mean pixels, you need to say that:

```
font-size: 30px
```

Answer (score 2):

Read this page for better understanding about fonts.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

Answer (score 1):

Should be `font-size: 30px` or something similar.  You need to specify the unit type.